# UITapGestureRecognizer not working on UIView in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, swift5

```
private let myView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .color(fromHexString: "EDF1F4")
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.layer.borderWidth = 2
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.color(fromHexString: "FFFFFF").cgColor
    
    // click event
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myViewTapped))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    
    return view
}()
```

As you can see I've added background color so background is not transparent, and also I've added `isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Yet this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above code on first line. I mean declaring myView.
Use `private lazy var myView: UIView = { ... }` instead of using `private let myView: UIView = { ... }` will resolve the problem.

I've faced this problem, so I think others might face the same. So I post this.
Thanks.